# EF6 Application Not Serializing Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I am working through my first entity framework/MVC application, and am having an issue on the API side of the application.  Here is the code

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Project.Models.StepByStep))]
public class StepByStep
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public int Version { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<StepPath> PathTable { get; set; }
}
```

And a sub class

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Project.Models.Step))]
public class Step
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //omitted numerous extraneous properties

    [DataMember]
    public int StepByStepId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual StepByStep StepApp { get; set; }

}
```

Using scaffolded controllers for MVC, I have created a StepByStep, and I have created 3 Steps attached to the StepByStep.  This is accurately reflected in the MVC controllers.

When using the API and making a call to the StepByStep entity, I expect to see tons of information from the steps, yet I see nothing, they are null.

```
<StepByStep xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Models" z:Id="i1">
<Id>1</Id>
 <Name>TestApp</Name>
 <PathTable i:nil="true"/>
 <Steps i:nil="true"/>
 <Version>1</Version>
</StepByStep>
```

Can anyone tell me why the API portion of my project cannot access/serialize the collections of Steps and Paths in the parent entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in your API calls you are including the child objects when retrieving the parent. There are certain situations where the child objects are not automatically included when using EF. Refer to the "Eager Loading" portion of this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

NOTE: It's called out in the article above, but I will mention it here: there is also the option to use lazy loading (where everything is always included), but this can be a very bad idea with serialization as you may end up pulling back way more data than you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  This post really made clear the differences between eager and lazy loading.  Got it working.